# How to keep two repositories synced, in which one repository is child of the other?

Tags: git, gitlab

My team is developing a framework and we will distribute it public. However, we want only parts of the source code to be public; the parts belonging to the core we want to keep private. We will do it by sharing only the DLLs of the core. Hence, the repository management will become a problem. How can we grant read permissions to only parts of the code?

### Possible Solutions

We thought in three possible solutions. They are:

1. Keep a single repository and manage the read permission of the folders;
2. Symlinks;
3. Break the repository in two and use git hooks.

#### 1. Keep a single repository and manage the read permission of a folder

Git can't do it. The closer solution is using gitolite, but it has folder-grained permission only for writing operations. Also, we are already using GitLab.

#### 2. Symlinks

As far as I know, this will not work. I think it might work only in one direction, that is  updating the public repository, but I'm not sure.

#### 3. Break the repository in two and use git hooks

I think this is the way to go. We would have to create two repositories, the *full repository* and the *public repository*. The full repository would be available only to the team working with the core and developing application modules. Then, they'll would have access to the entire source code.

The public repository is derived from the full repository. It would consist of parts of the full repository, such as the core DLL's and the application modules. The public repository will be designed only for users developing new application modules.

As both users and the core team will develop new application modules, we would need to configure a `post-receive` hook in both repositories. The script of the public repository would need to check the delta modifications regarding the full repository. Then, it would generate and apply a patch with those deltas. The same would be done for the full repository.

But, to check those deltas, the server would need to keep local copies of both repositories. First, the script would update these repositories, then check the new deltas. These deltas would be commited and, finally, the script would push the modifications to the source repository.

Are we in the right direction?

I'm afraid this solution is too complicated. Is there a better solution? How to keep two repositories synced, in which one repository is child of the other and this child can also have updates?

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this trivially with a [submodule](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). You create the private repository and the public subrepository independently, then add the public repository as a submodule of the private repository.

As long as the submodule is fully public, this should work fine. Something like this. First you create the public repository wherever, Github for example. Then for the private repository:

```
cd private
git init
git submodule add git://github.com/company/public public
git commit -m "Added public submodule"
```

Everything else should work as you expect, both repositories are separate repositories, but public is inherently a part of private.